# Persistence of NVIDIA Mosaic settings on Multi GPU system

Tags: nvidia-graphics-card, nvidia-quadro, nvidia-settings

I have a 4 GPU system with 12 4K monitors connected to it. I am using the NVIDIA Mosaic Technology to get a single desktop out of them. This part is successful.

Graphics Diver version: 348.40 on Windows 7 64bit

The problem is with the lack of persistence of the settings. Whenever a monitor is detached for any reason the system looses its Mosaic settings and I have to reconfigure it all over again; close to an hour wasted.

Is there a script that I can use to get the settings set by the NVIDIA Control Panel and then just use the script to setup/enable Mosaic instead of going through the NVIDIA Control Panel all the time?

PS. I am using 10ft DisplayPort cables.